# Change desktop's directory color

Tags: gnome, directory

As you can see in the picture below, there's something weird with my Desktop's folders.

When being inside the File's tool, the directories are painted with their colors.

As you can see in the Desktop's ones, this does not occur.

I wonder if there's a way to solve that.

Thanks in advance !!

[image: desktop]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Any gnome add ons?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot change the folder's icon. However, you can change the icon displayed for a specific folder by going to that folder's **Properties** (Ctrl+I).

Comment: @FedonKadifeli you should be kidding me... The properties menu does not no anything...

Comment: @David 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons on the desktop are currently provided by a Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons", or "Desktop Icons NG" on Ubuntu 21.10, not by the file manager Nautilus. These desktop extensions are more limited in functionality. In particular with the "Desktop Icons" extensions, desktop icons cannot be customized.

If you use "Desktop Icons" (default in 20.04), you may want to move over to "Desktop Icons NG". It has a lot more functionality, but I am not sure whether that extension effectively does support supports customizing desktop icons.

Comment: @DBG Does "Desktop Icons NG" allow you to change the icon? If you can confirm, I can edit my last sentence - can't test myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the last version of Folder Color:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color 
# apt-get update 
# sudo apt install python3-nautilus nautilus 
# sudo apt-get install folder-color 
$ nautilus -q
```

It should work with the desktop folder too, but you'll not see the menu (that is because of the extension itself).

Best regards.